# logstash 5.0.1: setup elasticsearch multiple indexes ouput for multiple kafka input topics

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration

I have a logstash input setup as

```
input {
  kafka {
  bootstrap_servers => "zookeper_address"
  topics => ["topic1","topic2"]
  }
}
```

I need to feed the topics into two different indexes in elasticsearch. Can anyone help me with how the ouput should be setup for such a task. At this time I am only able to setup

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "my_index"
    codec => "json"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

I need two indexes on the same elasticsearch instance say `index1` and `index2` which will be fed by messages coming in on `topic1` and `topic2`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to add `decorate_events` to your `kafka` input in order to know from which topic the message is coming

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "zookeper_address"
    topics => ["topic1","topic2"]
    decorate_events => true
  }
}
```

Then, you have two options, both involving conditional logic. The first is by introducing a filter for adding the correct index name depending on the topic name. For this you need to add

```
filter {
   if [kafka][topic] == "topic1" {
      mutate {
         add_field => {"[@metadata][index]" => "index1"}
      }
   } else {
      mutate {
         add_field => {"[@metadata][index]" => "index2"}
      }
   }
   # remove the field containing the decorations, unless you want them to land into ES
   mutate {
      remove_field => ["kafka"]
   }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "%{[@metadata][index]}"
    codec => "json"
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

Then second option is to do the if/else directly in the output section, like this (but the additional `kafka` field will land into ES):

```
output {
   if [@metadata][kafka][topic] == "topic1" {
     elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
       index => "index1"
       codec => "json"
       document_id => "%{id}"
     }
   } else {
     elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
       index => "index2"
       codec => "json"
       document_id => "%{id}"
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your exhaustive response. Much appreciated

Comment: And what can you do to use the same kafka topic as es index? add_field => {"[@metadata][index]" => "[kafka][topic]"} does not work for me

Comment: @hiaclibe no you need to use index => "%{[kafka][topic]}" in your elasticsearch output